# PowerShell - Check solution configuration debug/release

Tags: c#, powershell

How it is possible, to check the release settings (release/debug) from a solution with PowerShell?

My solution is for example, a SharePoint WSP file.

It is possible to get this information from a solution?

Comment: From a solution? Do you mean the configuration of the solution or of a distributed exe?

Comment: You could read the settings for each defined configuration (you can add more, so might not be limited to just debug and release) but I don't think that's what you mean. Do you want to know what the current selected configuration is? (This needs to be per project of course.)

Comment: I added details to my question :-) Thanks in advance

Comment: any solution with full source code sample?